# What Fictional Businesses exist in nWoD?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, chronicles-of-darkness-2e

I'm thinking that I want to ask my players to be employed within a given list of organizations, to flesh out the list I'd like to include some of the known in world companies. These shouldn't be secret or highly exclusive organizations even though they might have area's like that. Cheiron Group is a known example, given their description I imagine they must have employee's who are not hunters, in fact probably many employee's who have know knowledge of the supernatural. What other Organizations like this exist (They don't have to be normally PC playable)?

note: mentioning the Organizations public face, and it's secrets as well as where I can find more information is appreciated.

Comment: You're asking us to list businesses that exist in a setting that's practically identical to the one you live in? Why not just open a phone book?

Comment: @GMJoe obviously I was asking for game setting specific businesses, ones that don't exist in the real world. Like Deva Corporation. It is not a business in the real world. That's why the title says "Fictional"

Comment: I don't know why I bother to ask questions on here [the tOP forums](http://forum.theonyxpath.com/forum/main-category/main-forum/the-new-world-of-darkness/66912-corporations)  are a far better place to ask questions.)

Comment: The question you just linked asks for corporations with a tie to the supernatural world. The question you asked here asks for any and all organisations, whether or not they have supernatural ties. The question over there is *much* more narrowly scoped, and would likely be kept open and answered here.

Comment: @GMJoe I'm about 99% sure that any organization mentioned in any of the books has ties to the supernatural world. You broadened the scope to include things not mentioned in the books. Also the title of the question explicitly says "fictional" meaning any reference to say, the FBI, or military, etc, would not be fictional. In fact as a challenge, name a single fictitious organization in the books that does *not* have ties to the supernatural.

Answer (score 3):

- The Hototogisu in Blood and Smoke (p 266) is a small business conglomerate that is aware of the existance of Vampires and the Masquerade and uses said information to manipulate Kindred politics. The book only mentions that the companies making it up provide products and services in many unrelated fields, but doesn't mention any particular brand.
- The God-Machine Chronicle Anthologies mentions Deva Corporation as a company that is either basically G-M Infraestructure or a human endeavor that attempts to harness G-M technology for their own ends, or some mix of both. Demon, the Descent has some information on its origins and projects (p 53).
- The Seers of the Throne book brings one of my favorite organizations: The Federal Management Agency for Government Industry Loans, also known as "Famous Gil" by contractors, due to their acronym on the NY stock exchange (FGL). This organization funds all kinds of military and law enforcements projects, mainly weapons research. However, their money also sponsors other companies, shady or not. FGL is semi-publicly traded.

I will update my answer if I find others.

Comment: covering *Cheiron* wouldn't be bad, also I'm debating on whether "Utopio now" in Mortal Remains counts. Demon: the Descent has more on Deva. I didn't know about the other two you've mentioned though.

Comment: yeah "Utopia now" should be on the list. I might write it up if you don't have the book.

Comment: it's spelled "Hototogisu"